# Reading a text file into an undirected graph using adjacency list

Tags: java, adjacency-list, undirected-graph

I am trying to create an undirected graph using a text file with the following format:

```
0 5
4 3
0 1
9 12
6 4
5 4
0 2
11 12
```

I made a method to read the file and insert nodes/vertices into an arraylist. Each node/vertex has its own linked list within it to store neighboring nodes.This is what I have done so far.

```
//class for node/vertex
public class Node{
   //member variables
   private int vertex;
   
   LinkedList<Node> neighbors = new LinkedList<Node>();
   
   public Node (){
     this.vertex = vertex;
   }
}


//class for graph
public class Graph {
   private String filename;
   static ArrayList<Node> vertices;


   public Graph (){
     this.filename = filename;
     vertices = new ArrayList<>();
   }
   

   public String getFilename() {
        return filename;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }


    public static void file_to_array(String filename) {
        //chosen file's name in string type converted to file type
        File file = new File(filename);
        
        //scan the file with scanner object
        
        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (file);
                int n;
                while(scan.hasNextInt()) {
                    n = scan.nextInt();
                    Node new_node = new Node(n);
                    
                    //add node into the main static array, vertices
                    vertices.add(new_node);
                    
                }
                scan.close();
                    
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to implement the undirected part of the code from where I have started. I am also a bit unsure if the code I have written so far will be able to create the graph properly. I am still pretty new to implementing graphs, so any advice will be helpful.

Comment: 1) I recommended reading a line and not an `int` - easier to detect errors in input; 2) you don't want to create a new node if that node is already created - maybe you want a `HashMap` to (temporarily) store the nodes, mapping from the number to the Node (an array can also be used, if the number of nodes is known beforehand and their IDs is continuous, that is, 0,1,2,...(n-1) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
    String input =
        "0 5\r\n"
        + "4 3\r\n"
        + "0 1\r\n"
        + "9 12\r\n"
        + "6 4\r\n"
        + "5 4\r\n"
        + "0 2\r\n"
        + "11 12";
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);
    Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> graph = new HashMap<>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        int[] nums = Stream.of(scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
        graph.compute(nums[0], (k, v) -> v == null ? new HashSet<>() : v).add(nums[1]);
        graph.compute(nums[1], (k, v) -> v == null ? new HashSet<>() : v).add(nums[0]);
    }
    for (Entry<Integer, Set<Integer>> e : graph.entrySet())
        System.out.println(e);
```

output:

```
0=[1, 2, 5]
1=[0]
2=[0]
3=[4]
4=[3, 5, 6]
5=[0, 4]
6=[4]
9=[12]
11=[12]
12=[9, 11]
```